# Flow executes only the first apex method

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

My flow which runs the apex code below just execute the first method. Is something missing to execute also the second method?

```
public without sharing class MonthlyReport4FDB{
    
    @InvocableMethod(Label = 'monthly report 4 fdb' description='')  
    
    public static void MonthlyReport4FDB_all() {
        
        PageReference page = Page.MonthlyReport;
        
        Blob contentBlob = !Test.isRunningTest() ? page.getContentAsPDF() : Blob.valueOf('Hardcoded sample text for Test class');
        
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.VersionData = contentBlob;
        cv.Title =  System.today().year() + '_' + System.today().month() + '_fdb_all';
        cv.PathOnClient =  System.today().year() + '_' + System.today().month() + '_fdb_all.pdf';
        insert cv;                
        cv = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :cv.Id LIMIT 1];
        
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
        cdl.ShareType = 'I';
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = '001b000000Zps12AAB';
        insert cdl;
    }
    /* ####### */
    
    public static void MonthlyReport4FDB_out() {
        
        PageReference page2 = Page.MonthlyReport2; 
        
        Blob contentBlob2 = !Test.isRunningTest() ? page2.getContentAsPDF() : Blob.valueOf('Hardcoded sample text for Test class');
        
        ContentVersion cv2 = new ContentVersion();
        cv2.VersionData = contentBlob2;
        cv2.Title =  System.today().year() + '_' + System.today().month() + '_fdb_out';
        cv2.PathOnClient =  System.today().year() + '_' + System.today().month() + '_fdb_out.pdf';
        insert cv2;                
        cv2 = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :cv2.Id LIMIT 1];
        
        ContentDocumentLink cdl2 = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl2.ContentDocumentId = cv2.ContentDocumentId;
        cdl2.ShareType = 'I';
        cdl2.LinkedEntityId = '001b000000Zps12AAB';
        insert cdl2;
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method never calls the second one, so if you want to run them both with a single call from a flow, just add `MonthlyReport4FDB_out();` on the line after `insert cdl;`.
Otherwise, if you want to be able to called both method from a flow and they should be independent each other, you have to move `MonthlyReport4FDB_out` method in a new class in order to annotate it with `@InvocableMethod`, since [only one method in a class can have the `InvocableMethod` annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm).